# Can I make my app built with iOS7 SDK look like an iOS 6 app in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

I have an app that looks fine on iOS 6 and I'm trying to run as it is on iOS7.

Here's what I've done:

- At the project and target tab, set the deployment target to 5.1 and 5.1.1 respectively
- At the File Inspector tab of all my View Controllers, set Opens in "(Default 5.0)" and View as "iOS 6.1 and Earlier"

I have tested it on iPhone 5, 4 and 4s with iOS 7 and it works just fine. But now that I have published my app, it has the iOS 7 look and feel (and a lot of visual bugs caused by this change).

Some things that I noticed:

If I just build my app on Xcode, then later plug the device and run on it, it will have the iOS7 look and feel. But if I just build & run it directly on the device, it works perfectly (iOS 6 look and feel).

Comment: Not really related, but why? Why would you want to do such a thing???

Comment: @OscarApeland It's obvious, a lot of developers (and clients) don't want to commit the time and resources to updating apps for iOS 7. I'm sure that's why Hodes wants this. Of course now that it's past Feb. 1st, it's no longer possible to get away with the old look when you submit an app.

Comment: @OscarApeland Because the client want to. :(

Comment: @Hodes My condolences, better luck getting clients in the future. We need like programmer basic human rights to protect us from building for outdated technology and stuff

Comment: @OscarApeland, I know I'm probably in the minority, but I was interested in this topic because I have a couple of apps that aren't going on the AppStore, they're built for my own consumption, and I truthfully am not a fan of the iOS7 look (I expect I'll take some flak for that). At any rate, I'll probably have to update my apps, but it's surely a pretty big waste of time given that I've got an app I'm perfectly happy with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, my previous answer was wrong/out-dated.

Apple released an announcement stating that as of Feb 1st 2014 all apps running on iOS7 must be optimised for iOS 7.

This means that whether or not it is possible to make it look like iOS6 is irrelevant. If it runs on iOS7 it must be updated for iOS7.

https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a#top

Comment: Got the same answer from Apple. We talked to our client and he agreed to redesign the app.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, perhaps in your app delegate's `-load` method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@YES forKey:@"UIUseLegacyUI"];
```

However, Apple will most likely reject your app at this point for doing this, because Apple is now rejecting apps that have the old look and feel on iOS 7. Plus this loophole could possibly disappear at some point in the future, so your app could suddenly find itself with the updated look and feel with a future iOS update. But technically, this does make it possible to have the old look and feel when running on iOS 7 and when the app is built with the iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: Apple released an announcement (linked in my answer) saying that as of 1st Feb all apps must be optimised for iOS7.

Comment: @Fogmeister Hence why I said in my answer that Apple is now rejecting apps that have the old look and feel. But my answer technically accomplishes what the OP was asking for. He just can't submit it to the store or it will be rejected.

Comment: don't give advice that will definitely get rejected

Comment: @Daij-Djan Why a down vote? It answers the question, while stating that it can't be used in an app store build. It's the only answer that *answers* the question. The idea is to provide information, which my answer does. Someone could use this information for enterprise or ad-hoc distribution builds, or for a jailbreak app, so it's useful information to know.

Answer (score -1):

no, sdk7 apps will always look like ios7 apps on ios7

Comment: it depends on the target version

Comment: what does that even mean

Comment: my answer is totally right! apps built with sdk7 will be ios7-like

Comment: and since that is the only valid sdk, there is no legal way

Comment: if you know something we don't, please share it :)

Comment: @user2277872: I have the feeling that calling Daij-Djan a grasshopper has the roles reversed :-) So, enlighten us: I've got an iOS app linking against SDK7 with a Deployment Target of iOS 5, yet on iOS 7 it looks like an iOS 7 is supposed to look like. So, how do you change that?

Comment: @DarkDust, if you're targeting iOS 5, you will most likely still have a storyboard in your app. Just click on your VC, open the right side (in xcode 5), and click the icon that looks like a document. Travel down to Interface Builder Document, Builds for: iOS 5 and later. Then click View as: iOS 6.1 and Earlier. That will make it look like iOS 6 and before in the storyboard file. You can then just launch the iOS 6 or iOS 5 simulator in your case, and that should help.

Comment: @user2277872 thats what the OP said he had done and it doesnt work. It can't work for deployment as it is a 'debug' hack

Comment: @Daij-Djan ah, my mistake; must have read it wrong. Thank you for clearing that up. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: ... this down voting without leaving any comment is annoying: I AM right